# Como crear una "Sobrecarga de interfaces gráficas"

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quisiera Hacer que un formulario mostrara ciertas cosas al no mandarle parámetros desde su invocación y una manera completamente diferente al mandarle parámetros,Hasta ahora lo hacia con otro formulario pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de implementarlo

Comment: No se entiende que queres.. podrias mostrar un ejemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que te refieres a configurar tu formulario por medio de constructores.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
public class Formulario : Form
{
    // en el constructor sin parámetros (el que es llamado por el diseñador de formularios), puedes inicializar todo para que tenga el comportamiento "base"
    public Formulario()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // inicializas tus propiedades/campos para definir un comportamiento 
    }

    // este constructor llama al constructor base (el que no tiene parámetros), 
    // y ya luego puedes cambiar lo que quieras
    public Formulario(bool parametro1, string parametro2) : this()
    {
        // cambias las propiedades/campos para definir otro comportamiento
    }

    // también puedes tener constructores que llamen a otros constructores que
    // no son el sin parámetros
    public Formulario(bool parametro1, string parametro2, int parametro3) : this(parametro1, parametro2)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Windows Form` tiene soporte para herencia, pero lo implementa en dos forms diferentes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Inheriting Windows Forms with Visual C# .NET](https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_inherited_forms.html)

diseñas un `form base` el cual usas de base para crear otro form que hereda del primero, es lo mismo que harias cuando usas una `class` defines uno y lo usas para crear otro, pero son dos clases diferentes, por eso tendrias dos forms

Para que el diseñador funcione correctamente recomiendo que dejes un constructor sin parametros, sino tendras problemas

Pero puede agregar otros constructores a estos form pasandole los parametros que necesites, pero deberias instanciar siempre el form concreto que quieres utilizar, desde un `form base` no podras cambiar la logica para mostrar un `form heredado`